# Dispatch Event or Apex Call is not working in LWC Callback

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, platform-event, notification

I have developed an lwc which will trigger an apex call/display a toast message when a Platform event notification is received from the server.

I am following steps mentioned here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation

```
// Handles subscription
handleSubscribe() {

    // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
    const messageCallback = function(response) {
        
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
        
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Congrats!!',
            message: obj.data.payload.Message__c,
            variant: 'success',
        });

        this.dispatchEvent(event);

        console.log('Execution Point');
    };

    // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
    subscribe('/event/Asset_Change_Event__e', -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
        // Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
        console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
        this.subscription = response;
    });
}
```

I am able to print a simple log inside message callback [ I have already imported ShowToastEvent from Salesforce library]. However, if I try to show a toast message or try to call apex, it's not working.

Really appreciate your time to go through the details.

Please let me know if you have any idea what I am missing here.

Thank You.

Comment: It looks like the `this` context is lost inside messagecallback function and it generates an error while dispatching the event. Try binding the this context in by changing fourth last line to `subscribe('/event/Asset_Change_Event__e', -1, messageCallback.bind(this)).then(response => {`

Comment: Thanks, @manjit5190. It's working now. If you can add that as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `this` context is lost inside messagecallback function and it generates an error while dispatching the event.

Try binding the `this` context by changing to `subscribe('/event/Asset_Change_Event__e', -1, messageCallback.bind(this)).then(response => {`